# .NET Regex Negative Lookahead For Upper Case Letters

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Trying to work up an expression for a custom .NET application to extract ZIP codes from addresses.

The addresses are in a single line

```
12345 Example Street, NY 10019 United States
```

Used the following expression

```
\d{3,5}-\d{3,5}|\d{5}(?![A-Z]{2})
```

but this seems to be fetching both the `12345` as well as the ZIP code `10019`. Considering that I have mentioned only 2 upper case letters in the negative lookahead, shouldn't it be only considering the ZIP code that is preceded with the 2 letter NY code? What am I doing wrong here?

I am using the `|`operator as the ZIP codes are in `12345-12345` as well as `12345` formats

Please check the regex I am testing [here](https://regex101.com/r/B1uPpw/1)

Comment: Why are you testing a .NET regex in an online regex tester that does not support .NET regex syntax? Use regexhero.net or regexstorm.net.

Comment: Oops, didn't know that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a lookbehind here:

```
\d{3,5}-\d{3,5}|(?<=[A-Z]{2}\s+)\d{5}
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cd%7b3%2c5%7d-%5cd%7b3%2c5%7d%7c%28%3f%3c%3d%5bA-Z%5d%7b2%7d%5cs%2b%29%5cd%7b5%7d&i=12345+Example+Street%2c+NY+10019+United+States)

The `(?<=[A-Z]{2}\s+)` will require 2 uppercase letters and then 1 or more whitespaces before 5 digits.

To make sure you match specified number of digits, you may use word boundaries `\b`:

```
\b(?:\d{3,5}-\d{3,5}|(?<=[A-Z]{2}\s+)\d{5})\b
```

See [another demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb%28%3F%3A%5Cd%7B3%2C5%7D-%5Cd%7B3%2C5%7D%7C%28%3F%3C%3D%5BA-Z%5D%7B2%7D%5Cs%2B%29%5Cd%7B5%7D%29%5Cb&i=12345%20Example%20Street%2C%20NY%2010019%20United%20States).

Comment: Thank you so much. Works like a charm